# Parsing data into struct

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios

I'm working on a project where I need to communicate with a device via the TCP/IP-protocol. 
The device sends an large amount of data which I somehow want to parse into some objects/structs.

Datapackage example (in the TCP buffer[]):

```
[64] [1] [78] [244] [77] [189] [249] [149] hcurrent
[64] [1] [78] [247] [89] [95] [104] [85] htarget
[0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] qcurrent
[188] [220] [97] [3] [66] [62] [0] [0] kcurrent
[66] [0] [102] [103] [66] [99][153] [154] mcurrent
[253] [191] [246] [74] [170] [216] [242] [29] fmode
[102] [191] [246] [74] [178] [44] [92] [72] tmil
[137] mode
```

Now this package frame is identified as:

```
 double hcurrent
 double htarget
 double qcurrent
 float kcurrent
 float mcurrent
 float fmode
 float tmil
 unsigned char mode
```

My idea was that I somehow could parse the data directly into a struct which had the same structure as above. 
Of course it will be neccessary to identify some key values to determine which kind of data it is.

How can this be done?

Since I'm coding for an iOS device it has to be objective-C or C(++).

EDIT (method tested for copying each part of the datagram into struct):
Small Java implementation where i try to read the first 4 bytes `[0] [0] [1] [5]`:

```
byte[] read = new byte[4]; 
int length = 0;
while (length < read.length) {
    len = iStream.read(read, len, read.length);
}
int ByteLength = (int)unsignedIntToLong(read);
ByteLength = ByteLength-5;
state = 1; // Continue and work with next data.
```

And the bit manipulation method:

```
public long unsignedIntToLong(byte[] b) 
{
    long l = 0;
    l |= b[0] & 0xFF;
    l <<= 8;
    l |= b[1] & 0xFF;
    l <<= 8;
    l |= b[2] & 0xFF;
    l <<= 8;
    l |= b[3] & 0xFF;
    return l;
}
```

So i fetch the first 4 bytes i mentioned earlier which determines something specific, and in the end an find the length of `465`. My plan is to repeat this process with all other parts of the received data.

Comment: "a large amount of *data* which I *somehow* want to parse into *some objects/structs*"  I don't think you are being vague enough...

Comment: @borrrden what would you like to know in addition to my information, i will try to explain further.

Comment: What is "64" originally?  What is the data type of your buffer object?  Will the buffer always come in this order with all of the values?

Comment: I was just contacted by the device manufacture and it seems that i have got a wrong API description. I will have to update my question to suite the correct API.

Comment: If the memory layout of your struct exactly fits the byte layout of your telegram, it is possible to just memcpy (C++) the telegram buffer to a preallocated struct memory area. _But_ there are a few traps you have to be aware of, like endian issues, encoding of float values and you have to have an exact understanding of the memory layout of your struct. But it is possible to use this approach.

Comment: @JavaCake you haven't given us enough information regarding how this buffer is specified, it sounds like you're suggesting that the contents could appear in any order...

Comment: @nabulke, theres actually still something wrong with the documentation. The `kcurrent` variable should have been half the size (32-bit) to fit the example. But if we assume this ia a doc mistake, can i copy the entire example into my struct with memcpy?

Comment: @Benj, the buffer is specified in the order as shown in the example, every value position (n) is buffer[n]. So its not random.

Comment: @JavaCake - I answered this earlier but deleted my own answer because I decided that I'd misunderstood exactly what you were trying to do.  I've undeleted it again because it does explain the problems with trying to treat contigious binary fields as if they were a struct.

Comment: @JavaCake - In that case, my answer is probably valid.

Comment: As you can see from all the comments and Benjis answer, the memcpy approach has quite a few traps to offer. Why not go down a more conventional road, and copy your telegram into some byte vector like std:vector<unsigned char> and implement the streaming operator<< and operator>> for your struct. In those streaming operator you copy each data value from the vector stream to each data field. It's way easier to program and for me the performance was good enough.

Comment: @nabulke, that sounds interesting could you by any chance show me an small example to give a better practical understand? Thanks.

Comment: First you need to know whether the data is big-endian or little-endian.

Comment: And the "float" data items are presumably actually "double" (since they're 8 bytes long), so you can't just assign the bytes to a "float" location.

Comment: @HotLicks, im looking into that problem right now. As you say the float is the same size as double, which does not make much sense.

Comment: @HotLicks its using big endian. So (int) `[0],[0],[1],[209]` is `0+0+(1*256)+209`

Comment: Re your latest update, it's best if the routine somehow communicates how many bytes it's "consumed".

Comment: But i cannot really avoid interpretation of the values as i do with my `unsignedIntToLong`, it could be nice if there was a much more efficient way to do that.

Comment: Trust me -- that is the least of the inefficiencies you'll have to deal with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest problem you're going to have is that structs don't store data in a completely contiguous form, they align data [acording to word boundaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)

This means that you can't simply define a struct and then cast your buffer[] to it if the buffer didn't contain a struct to begin with.  Instead what you probably need to do is declare a struct and then memcpy each part of the buffer[] in one field at a time using apointer offset into the buffer[].

If this approach is too cumbersome, it's often possible to turn off structure alignment so that a structure can represent completely packed data.  MSVC allows the use of [#pragma pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to do this.  This approach does however slow memory access to the structure.

**EDIT:** Here's an example which shows how you can use a template function to read any type from a buffer and then update an offset into that buffer.  You can use this method to safely parse any number of types into a structure one by one:

```
// We want to copy raw data to this structure
// but the short will cause it to be unaligned
struct _parsed_structure
{
    int a;
    int b;
    short c;
    int d;
} parsed_structure;

template<typename T>
void read_and_update_offset (int & offset, char * buffer, T & var)
{
    T * pInt = (T*)(buffer + offset);
    var = *pInt;
    offset += sizeof(T);
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Here's a buffer which we know contains ints and shorts, we could just cast it to our structure
    // but this will cause errors because the structure will not be aligned properly.
    char buffer[] = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0 };

    // Read the first int from the buffer into the structure
    int offset = 0;
    read_and_update_offset(offset, buffer, parsed_structure.a);
    read_and_update_offset(offset, buffer, parsed_structure.b);
    read_and_update_offset(offset, buffer, parsed_structure.c);
    read_and_update_offset(offset, buffer, parsed_structure.d);

    // Print the values
    std::cout << 
        parsed_structure.a << " " <<
        parsed_structure.b << " " <<
        parsed_structure.c << " " <<
        parsed_structure.d << " " << std::endl;

    // Look the size of our structure is different than the size of our buffer due to alignment
    std::cout <<
        "sizeof(buffer)" << "==" << sizeof(buffer) << " " <<
        "sizeof(parsed_structure)" << "==" << sizeof(parsed_structure) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `#pragma pack` not an OS related operation? Im wondering if this is possible in my case (Mac OS X / iOS)?

Comment: #pragma pack is not standard that's for sure, it is supported on a number of OSes though, (including some UNIX flavours) so it might work... if not there'll be some other very similar feature... I've seen #pragma align before.

Comment: @JavaCake - Do you want to know how to use #pragma pack or are you asking about copying fields out one at a time?  (Which is by the way probably a better approach)

Comment: I see alot of work in the manual method, but how much performance are we talking about?

Comment: @JavaCake If you use the method I've shown above then you'll do a small amount of processing to put the data into the structure.  If you use something like #pragma pack, you'll incurr a performance penalty when you put data into the structure and when you take it out...

Comment: Im just considering the amount of code when i have to make this process for 15 different structs which my telegram will occupy. But i see the performance problem with `#pragma back`.

Comment: I've updated this to show what happens if you have unaligned data, noticed that the struct is now a different size than the buffer.

Comment: @JavaCake, if you're worried about code complexity you could give each struct a constructor which takes a pointer to the buffer and a reference to the offset?  Then each struct would know how to parse it's self.  Each constructor would just consist of calls to read_and_update_offset()

Comment: I understand the problem scenario you have made in the code example, and i will take that into account. Hopefully it will never occur acording to the device documentation. But as you mention i am indeed worried about code complexity.

Answer (score 2):

The usual approach to something like this is to write methods `nextInt`, `nextDouble`, etc that will read bytes from the stream (in proper "endian" order) and return a value of the indicated type, updating a pointer or index into the array as they do.  This is much more manageable than trying to in-line the conversions, and can be quite efficient.  (You can make the methods C++ vs Objective-C for efficiency.)

Comment: This approach sounds interesting. But wont i loose the entire idea with the struct?

Comment: I tried to implement it as a state-machine in Java, which is quite straightforward. But i need to find some alternative in C++. Will update the question in a moment.

Comment: @Hot Licks - This is pretty much the example I gave in my answer except that rather than using nextInt() etc, I just use one template function which works for all types.

Comment: @Benj -- True.  Either approach is valid.  However, when you use the data type in the structure to "cue" you as to the data type in the data stream, you require that they exactly match in both type and length.  In the OP's example they do not match.

Comment: @JavaCake -- I'm a little curious as to why your Java implementation couldn't be used with C++.  There's essentially nothing you can do in Java that can't be done in C++.

Comment: @HotLicks, its pretty much the same implementation, except its a combi of C++ and Objective-C. But they are most likely identical with my Java code.